# Microsoft Word Performing computations

Tags: if-statement, ms-word

I'm attempting to do a conversion from military time to regular time, however word is not evaluating anything. Honestly this is really counter intuitive.

Anyways The first thing I tried was:

```
{SET H { =INT({MERGEFIELD ARRIVAL_HOUR})}

{IF "{MERGEFIELD ARRIVAL_HOUR}" > 12 "{REF H}-12" "{MERGEFIELD ARRIVAL_HOUR}"}
```

and word gives me Invalid OP code : Ok, so then I tried:

```
    {IF "{MERGEFIELD ARRIVAL_HOUR \* MERGEFORMAT }" 
>12 "{={MERGEFIELD ARRIVAL_HOUR \*MERGEFORMAT } - 12}PM" "" }
```

and I get "15-12PM" displayed on the page. So why isn't it doing the computation?

Comment: I didn't even know you could do this in word, but it looks like you need something like this: `{ COMPARE { MERGEFIELD ARRIVAL_HOUR} > 12 }` rather than what you have. I got this from here: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/examples-of-if-fields-HP005187676.aspx

Comment: Can you edit the field code and use the optional parameter?  For example, DATE \@ "M/d/yy h:mm am/pm"  Here is some help on that: http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/insert-and-format-field-codes-in-word-2010-HA101830917.aspx#BM9